# Connecting the Login page with database failed

Tags: c#, asp.net, database

I am trying to connect my database with the login.aspx file, but I keep getting an error:

**SqlDataSource1 Type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.SqlDataSource' does not have a public property named "'OnClick'."**

My main body code of my login.aspx file code is:

```
<div id="pageBody">
                <form id="loginForm" runat="server">
                    <div class="imgcontainer">
                        <img src="/packages/img_avatar2.png" alt="Avatar" class="avatar">
                    </div>
                    <div class="container">
                        
                        <asp:textbox id="usernameLoginTextbox" placeholder="Enter username" runat="server"/>
                        <asp:Label ID="Label1" Visible="false" CssClass="error px-5 py-1" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
                        
                        <asp:textbox type="password" id="passwordLoginTextbox" placeholder="Enter password" runat="server"/>
                        <asp:Label ID="Label2" Visible="false" CssClass="error px-5 py-1" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
                        
                        <asp:Button runat="server" id="loginButton" Text="Log Me In Amigo" OnClick="loginButton_Click" CssClass="cancelbtn"/>
                        <asp:Label ID="success" CssClass="bg-success px-5 py-2" ForeColor="White" Visible="false" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
                    </div>
                </form>
                <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" OnClick ="loginButton_Click" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Table]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
            </div>
```

And the database query code is:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Table]
(
    [Id] INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
    [username] NCHAR(50) NULL, 
    [password] NCHAR(15) NULL
)
```

Lastly my loginButton_Click code is:

```
        protected void loginButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from login where uname=@username and passwd=@password", con);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", usernameLoginTextbox.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", passwordLoginTextbox.Text);

            SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            if (sdr.Read())
            {
                Label1.Visible = false;
                Label2.Visible = false;
                success.Visible = true;
                success.Text = "Login successful";
            }
            else
            {
                Label1.Visible = true;
                Label2.Visible = true;
                Label1.Text = "Username incorrect";
                Label2.Text = "password incorrect";
            }
            con.Close();
        }
```

Does anybody know what the solution of the problem may be or if I can substitute the OnClick with something else?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: have you read the `SqlDataSource` documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.sqldatasource?view=netframework-4.8? It doesn't have an `OnClick` event. Remove it from the control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<asp:SqlDataSource tag has no OnClick property defined, you need to remove  "OnClick ="loginButton_Click" from asp:SqlDataSource tag. Looks like accidental copy paste error, you already have the same onClick inside <asp:Button.